# automated job triggering and cron job execution in php

Tags: php

I am currently developing a notification system which gets data from a BUG tracking system and checks if a specific BUG was attended or not within a threshold time , say 2 weeks. If its more than 2 weeks , an automated email should be sent to 2 persons(person who created the BUG and person from the QA team).

I am running apache, php, curl on win server 2003. I am currently thinking about running a php script every night, which monitors all the BUG reports to check if any of them crossed the threshold time , and send an email if necessary. i am currently relying on windows task scheduler to automate email delivery- running a batch file with a curl -xxxx command  in it.

Is there a better way to implement this Job monitoring script? Any advise will  be really helpful and appreciated.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

For scheduled tasks, it's usually better to run PHP via the command line executable than issuing HTTP requests. For example, in cron

```
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php /path/to/my/php/script.php
```

This way, you aren't subject to execution time limits or HTTP delays.

You can do the same via the Windows task scheduler.

Comment: And actually my main problem is my job monitoring logic. Is there a better way to achieve what I explained ??

Comment: @Eswar Not sure what `php5-cli` is, I've always just used the standard PHP binary. I think your logic is sound

Comment: @phil.. nevermind about the php-cli, i was concerned about the logic, i was wondering if theres a better way to monitor the jobs. I really dont have any problem executing the cron jobs, sorry about the php5-cli, i have used linux php-client so much that i couldnt get it out of my mind, in other words i meant the php executable!!!